# Profit Maximization....

Tags: calculus

A company can produce a maximum of 1500 Widgets in a year. If they sell $x$ widgets during the year their profit is given by $P(x) = 30000000 - 360000 x + 750 x^2 – \frac{x^3}{3}$

**How many widgets should they try to sell in order to maximize their profit ?**

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score -1):

Pleas notice that you didn't put the minimum effort in the problem. What have you tried? Where is the difficulty?

It seems like a usual maximization problem. Take the derivative and find the maximum of the function $P(x)$.

If you're lazy you can even just plot it on some program.

By the way:

$P'(x) = -x^2+1500x-360000$

In order to find stationary points, impose $P'(x)\ge 0$. You get $P'(x)$ negative until 300 (first solution of $P'(x)=0$), then positive until 1200 (second solutions of $P'(x)=0$) and then negative again after it. So $x=1200$ gives you the max of P(x) and that's the number of widget  you should sell in order to maximize the profit